# Property ExplicitLeft does not exist

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

I'm having an a error when I'm creating or editing a TEXT OBJECT on Fastreport using Delphi 7.
Here's the error:

> Error reading TextTS->ExplicitLeft: Property ExplicitLeft does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this [thread](http://goo.gl/Iveq8F) in the Fast Reports Forum

Answer (score 3):

As per @RUZZ's link:
You are getting this error because you're opening a DFM file that was created by a Delphi version newer than  D7.
`ExplicitLeft` is a property unknown in D7, is was added in a later version (not sure which).
There are three options:

1. Use a newer version of Delphi.
2. Open the dfm file in a text editor and remove the `Explicit*` references.
3. Download Delphi DFM convertor: http://www.maxidix.com/products/delphi-dfm-converter It converts a post Delphi 7 DFM into a Delphi 7 DFM.

Needless to say if your program accesses post Delphi 7 properties you'll need to do some refactoring of your code.