# Property UserMAPI does not exist

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, fastreport

I am currently trying to solve an issue with FastReport 4 for Delphi 2007.

Everytime I try to open the FastReport component in my application, the following error is given to me :

> Error reading frxMailExport1.UseMAPI : Property UseMAPI does not exist.

I found this answerless thread [Property ExplicitLeft does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478339/property-explicitleft-does-not-exist) that kind of looks like my problem. The solutions proposed in this thread are implying that this DFM file has been compiled with a newer version of Delphi.

The thing is that one of my collegue is using exactly the same source code as me and when he compiles the application, everything works fine.

Also, I looked at the FastReport forums for answers, without result.

Is there anything I can do to get this to work? Note that I have the lastest Delphi 2007 build of FastReport.

Comment: FastReport comes as a separate product (which is in some *light* version part of a Delphi distribution as far as I know). Have you checked that you are both using exactly the same version and source code ? Just a sidenote; properties can be dropped also in newer versions, so having a newer version doesn't always mean that it's fully compatible with the old one (even though it should happen rarely due to backward compatibility in high quality products).

Comment: Turns out that the dates of the DCU and PAS files for frxExportMail  where different on the computer of my collegue and when I changed them for the older ones, it worked.

It looks like the newest version is not fully compatible with Delphi 2007. I'm now searching for a way to compile it the good way.